# swift: unrecognized selector sent to instance signal sigabrt

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

i want play a video in my app, i use `avplayer` without problem but after ending video, app is crashing and i get this error:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f950bf6d1a0 2015-10-09
>   14:42:42.769 Carpooling[47925:1543415] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[Carpooling.ViewController playerItemDidReachEnd:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7f950bf6d1a0'

what is my mistake?

```
lazy var playerLayer:AVPlayerLayer = {

    let player = AVPlayer(URL:  NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("BWWalkthrough", ofType: "mp4")!))
    player.muted = true
    player.allowsExternalPlayback = false
    player.appliesMediaSelectionCriteriaAutomatically = false
    var error:NSError?

    // This is needed so it would not cut off users audio (if listening to music etc.
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
    } catch var error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    }



    var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
    playerLayer.videoGravity = "AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill"

    playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    player.play()
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.None
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:",
        name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
        object: player.currentItem)
    return playerLayer
    }()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: check if you outlet is connected properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're registering an observer with `NSNotificationCenter` and telling the observer to call `playerItemDidReachEnd:` when it gets notified but your code doesn't implement `playerItemDidReachEnd:` therefore the code can't find the method and crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Upper answer by @Bensarz is correct. You are missing the receiver method.

Add the below method

```
func playerItemDidReachEnd(playerItem: AVPlayerItem) {
    //Do your stuff here
}
```